# How does phpunit command make search class testing?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I use windows.
For example I have some website with a structure smth like this:

```
site/
    engine/
       ModelClass.php
    www/
       index.php
    tests/
       ModelCalssTest.php
phpunit.bat
```

Where should be store phpunit.bat to run test ModelClassTest.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not need to store a `phpunit.bat` at all. It should be in your `PATH`.

Just install it via PEAR and be done. If you don't want to do that and you have it locally on the system or your WANT the phpunit sources in your version control (some people want that) it doesn't matter where your phpunit.bat is really. Project root is fine, somewhere in `vendor/phpunit/phpunit.bat` is fine too if you have an ant or phing or .bat file in your project root that lets you say `"run tests now"`.

---

What i currently observe as "best-practice" is to put your `phpunit.xml.dist` (the config file) in your **application root** so that people can just:

- get the source
- type `phpunit`
- see that everything works

See: [**`a sample project made by the phpunit author`**](https://github.com/thePHPcc/bankaccount)

What I've also seen is that people put that config file in their "tests" folder to have a "clean project root". Also works out nicely.

References: [**`Documentation on the phpunit xml file`**](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html)

Comment: It doesn't make clear a little bit, sorry. If phpunit.bat is used for different projects and it strored under the PATH enviroment, so how phpunit.bat will know whats project I'm going to test?

Comment: @Anthony you `cd C:/to/your/project` and enter `phpunit` there. It knows from where it was executed. Just like `dir` knows which folder you are in. Thats why people usually just install it from pear and not for each project.

Answer (score 2):

I usually have `phpunit` executable in my PATH and keep a structured directory for tests similar to yours. Then you should [configure your phpunit using the xml file](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html) in which you can include common options and most important a bootstrap file which contains the one time setup needed for your tests. if you put the xml file in the tests folder you can have a structure like this

```
tests
├── bootstrap.php
├── TestEnvironment.php
├── application
│   ├── controllers
│   │   └── IndexControllerTest.php
│   ├── forms
│   │   └── UserTest.php
│   ├── helpers
│   │   └── Html2TxtTest.php
│   └── modules
│       └── admin
│           └── models
│               ├── LayoutManagerTest.php
│               ├── ScriptOptionsTest.php
│               ├── ServiceTest.php
│               ├── TemplatesTest.php
│               └── UsersFinderTest.php
└── phpunit.xml
```

and run tests as you wish with commands like

```
phpunit # run all tests
phpunit application # run all tests inside application folders
phpunit application/forms/UserTest.php # run all tests inside the given file
```

So, as far as you have phpunit in the PATH there's no problem in running it, if you can't have it in your PATH, consider put it in the tests folder and run it from there.

This works well in Unix environments, but it should work also on Win32.

Comment: Tnx. Where is phpunit.bat (or phpunit.sh) stored in yours example pathtree?

Comment: You should keep it in your path. On Windows you can do echo %PATH% on the prompt to discover it (I don't remember PATH on win). If you don't want to do that keep it under tests folder, but in that way you'll have to copy it across different projects.